# Switch não está preenchendo todos os dados

Tags: javascript

Olá, tenho um Grid e estou fazendo algumas alterações de dados para exibição, explicando melhor, no meu banco de dados eu salvo os dados com apenas um valor: "V", "A", "O", e quero fazer alterações para exibição, como mostra o `switch`.

```
function criador_linhas(s, e) {
    if (s.rowType == "data") {
        switch (s.data.CatVen_Tipo) {
            case "V":
                s.data.CatVen_Tipo1 = "Venda Avulsa";
                break;
            case "A":
                s.data.CatVen_Tipo1 = "Ambos";
                break;
            case "O":
                s.data.CatVen_Tipo1 = "Orçamento/Projeto";
                break;
            default:
                s.data.CatVen_Tipo1 = "Erro";
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Meu banco de dados:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O problema é o seguinte, ele preenche alguns valores, mas outros ele deixa vazio, como mostra a imagem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Meu DataGrid:

```
@(Html.DevExtreme().DataGrid()
                                            .ShowBorders(true)
                                            .Height(355)
                                            .Selection(s => s.Mode(SelectionMode.Single))
                                            .DataSource(Model, new string[] { "CatVen_Codigo" })
                                            .Columns(columns =>
                                            {
                                                columns.Add().DataField("CatVen_Codigo").Width(100).Caption("Código");
                                                columns.Add().DataField("CatVen_Descricao").Caption("Descrição");
                                                columns.Add().DataField("CatVen_Tipo1").Width(120).Caption("Tipo");
                                                columns.Add().DataField("CatVen_Ativo").Width(120).Caption("Situação");
                                            }).OnSelectionChanged("selection_changed")
                                            .Paging(p => p.PageSize(10))
                                            .FilterRow(f => f.Visible(true))
                                            .HeaderFilter(f => f.Visible(true))
                                            .OnRowPrepared("criador_linhas")
                                            .GroupPanel(p => p.Visible(true))
                                            .GroupPanel(p => p.EmptyPanelText("Arraste uma coluna até aqui para agrupar por essa coluna"))
                                            .NoDataText("Nada encontrado")
                                            .Grouping(g => g.AutoExpandAll(false))
                                            .RemoteOperations(true)
                                            .LoadPanel(loadPanel => loadPanel.Enabled(false))
                                            .Scrolling(scrolling => scrolling.Mode(GridScrollingMode.Infinite))
)
```

Comment: Confira se o campo `s.rowType` está sendo preenchido como `data`, ou até mesmo retire a validação para testar. É bom também verificar no console do navegador se não está tendo algum erro, pois se houver erro no preenchimento como por exemplo um acesso à um objeto inválido vai acontecer de quebrar também.

Comment: Verifique pelo console.log ou pelo alert se a informação está chegando corretamente, e se não há espaços ou outro tipo de caractere adicional na string.